Cleaner Logic Based on Type than Typemapping in Typescript
In an application I am working on, I have this grid system. Basically, we show the user rows and columns.
I have this large type defining each of the columns.
export interface Record {
age: number,
ID: number,
item1: number,
item2: string,
item3: string,
item4: number,
... etc (there is a bunch of these columns)
}
I have logic I want to perform based on the type of this.
In a front-end application, the user can select a column and perform logic related to that column. Unfortunately, when this logic is performed, I only have the list of columnNames as strings we using to define the dropdown (not an instance of the row). I need to be able to call different functions based on this type. Lets say the user selects a number column, I want to be able to call functionA based on type defined in the interface. If the user selects a string column, then I want to call functionB.
I haven't been able to find a clean way to do this without keeping 2 separate lists up to date (technical debt and all that).
I know I can use a typeMapping like
export const typeMapping: { [key in keyof Record]: string } = {
  age: "number",
  ID: "number",
  item1: "number",
  item2: "string",
  item3: "string",
  item4: "number",
  ...
};

or I can do a function like
export function isStringProperty<K extends keyof Record>(key: K | undefined): boolean {
  if (!isPresent(key)) {
    return false;
  }
  const stringProperties: (keyof TradeRecord)[] = [
    'item1', 'item2'
  ];
  return stringProperties.includes(key);
}

But both of these methods require the maintenance of a second list that we need to keep up to date with any new columns. Is there some more clean way to do this without needing to update both lists in tandem. Thanks!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can look at in our IDEs and play around with. Right now you're referring to undeclared things named Record and TradeRecord and I don't see where two lists are being maintained.  If you make it easy for us to work with, you'll make it more likely to get an answer that helps you.

Why not just if (typeof record[key] === 'string') { ... }?
